# PHP5 Soap Function does not return, script stops

Tags: php, soap

I am making a SOAP call using PHP 5, after the call, no matter what I pass as the parameteres, the soap function simply does not return a value and the execution of the script seems to stop.  I have tried with and without the try, and there is no change. I have passed empty $params, non empty params, etc.

After this line: $client->getClient($params);

There is an echo for b, which never gets echoed.  It's as if the script just stops running after the call is made.  There is no error displayed, and nothing shows up in the error_log.  Very frustrating, any ideas?

$params = array();

```
$client = new SoapClient("https://sandbox.paymentsgateway.net/WS/Client.wsdl",array(
                    'soap_version'=>SOAP_1_1,
                    'exceptions'=>true,
                    'trace'=>1,
                    'cache_wsdl'=>WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
                    'location'=>'https://sandbox.paymentsgateway.net/WS/Client.svc/basic'
                ));

     try
    {
        echo '4';
        $client->getClient($params);
        echo 'b';
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If working in WSDL-mode you must not use the `location`-parameter. They should be mutually exclusive. Try removing the `location`-parameter.

**EDIT** (because the above didn't help):

Try to check if the `SoapClient` could parse the WSDL correctly:

```
print_r($client->__getFunctions());
print_r($client->__getTypes());
```

Is there any authentication in place, e.g. HTTP authentication on the WSDL document?

Does your script run into the execution time or memory limit? It looks as though you're connecting to a .NET webswervice and their WSDLs tend to grow quite large - it may take some time for PHP to parse the WSDL.

Comment: I've tried removing the location param but that does not make any difference.

Comment: Hi - The script ends after about 2 seconds.  It's able to parse the WSDL, I can even call a specific function that is not createClient.  I can call getClient on it with the proper params and it works.  If I pass an empty string as param, I get an error back from the web service but the moment I pass anything else, it seems to fail.  It's possible I am not passing the correct params, but I am not even getting back an error, and the rest of the script just stops working.. any ideas on why that would happen?

Comment: Can you try to connect to the webservice through some other client? Can you setup some sniffing on what's happening on the TCP/IP connection when you're running your code? Quite hard to debug otherwise.